# JQUERY PHP on Chrome giving a 500 error for GET Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter

[image]

The PHP Code is here and utilizes the [Twitter API Exchange PHP File](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php)

```
<?php

    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');        

    $settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token'            => 'whatever',
    'oauth_access_token_secret'     => 'whatever',
    'consumer_key'                  => 'whatever',
    'consumer_secret'               => 'whatever'
    );


    $query = "%23georgeezra";
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
    $requestMethod = "GET";
    $getfield = '?q='.$query.'&count=5';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $result = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();
    echo $result;

?>
```

I have run this query on the Dev tool on Twitter and the query executes as required but on Chrome and Firefox it gives a 500 ( Internal Server Error ) error while running on Apache2 server and using JQuery version 2.1.1

The JQuery Code :

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ezra.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {

            if (typeof response.errors === 'undefined' || response.errors.length < 1) {

                var $tweets = $('<ul></ul>');
                $.each(response, function(i, obj) {
                    $tweets.append('<li>' + obj.text + '</li>');
                });

                $('.tweets-container').html($tweets);

            } else {
                $('.tweets-container p:first').text('Response error');
            }
        },
        error: function(errors) {
            $('.tweets-container p:first').text('Request error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Turn PHP error reporting on, or check your apache logs

Comment: Are the spaces between `-` and `>buildOauth` in the original code or a copying error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = json_decode(...)
```

should call `json_encode`, not `json_decode`. And `$assoc = TRUE` is not an appropriate second argument to `json_encode`.

You also need to add:

```
dataType: "json"
```

to the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Thanks I removed the $assoc and changed it to json_encode but it's still not working.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'twitter_proxy.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/Web Project/ezra.php on line 3, referer: http://localhost/Web%20Project/artist1.html

However it makes no sense because artist1.html has no such line

Comment: There is no twitter_proxy.php either

Comment: The line is in `ezra.php`, not `artist1.html`.

Comment: That's what the error message is complaining about -- there's no `twitter_proxy.php`, but `ezra.php` requires it.

Comment: ezra.php is shown in the question, the require_once wants TwitterAPIExchange.php

Comment: Are you sure you loaded that version of the code into the server directory? I can't imagine why PHP would complain about a different filename than the one in the `require` line.

Comment: What does `performRequest` return? If it returns an array or object, you should be using `json_encode`, not `json_decode`. If it returns a JSON string, you can just echo it directly, you don't need to decode it.

Comment: If you decode it, then you need to encode it again before echoing it. You can't just echo an array or object, the client expects JSON.

Comment: I just copied it verbatim from the TwitterAPIExchange file readme on github, seemed straightforward enough to just blindly copy

Comment: I see no call to `json_decode` on that page. The example there contains: `echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->setPostfields($postfields)
    ->performRequest();`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the TwitterAPIExchange.php file needed cURL to work.

I ran : `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` followed by `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` and that did it.